# Dynamically load XAML with Custom Converters defined in XAML attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to load XAML dynamically from string/file. The problem is XAML contains some references for custom converters and on loading, it fails with error

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:DataGridApp.Converter}CollectionConverter'

My dynamic XAML is simple

```
<UserControl 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:DataGridApp.Converter">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converter:CollectionConverter x:Key="CollectionConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
            <DataGrid
                      ItemsSource='{Binding Path=dynamicProperty, Converter={StaticResource CollectionConverter}}'/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C# code for reading XAML dynamically

```
private FrameworkElement LoadViewFromMemory(string template)
{
   using (Stream s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(template)))
    {
       return XamlReader.Load(s) as FrameworkElement;
    }
}
```

Converter class simply converts any object to the collection of object

```
public class CollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            List<dynamic> d = new List<dynamic> {value};
            return d;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to load XAML with converters dynamically?

**Answer:**

As suggested by @mike, I have to add an assembly reference in XAML clr-namespace for converter

```
<UserControl 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:DataGridApp.Converter;assembly=DataGridAppProj">
```

Comment: why do you serialize XAML in the first place?

Comment: Also if you want to deserialize the converter you need to have the converter class in your project!

Comment: I want to dynamically construct some XAML Controls as XAML string for one project, Converter class is already inside project.

Comment: Add an assembly name qualifier to your converter’s namespace mapping.  The runtime doesn’t know where to find it.  `clr-namespace` mappings *without* an assembly name can only be used at project compile time.  At runtime, there is no notion of “projects”.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mike, for your suggestion!. It works now.